# how to change variables in different components

Tags: angular, components

I have two components - one mainComponent, one MenuComponent.
from MenuComponent, I want to change variable in mainComponent.

```
import { Injectable, Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
@Component({
  selector: 'app-componentmain',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class ComponentMainContent {
  public selectedGroup : any;
```

in menu component:

```
import { ComponentMainContent } from '../main/main.component';
@Component({
..
providers: [ComponentMainContent]
..

export class MenuListItemComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private ComponentMain: ComponentMainContent,

..
showGroup(item: NavItem){
     this.ComponentMain.selectedGroup = 'test'; - nothing is happening
  }
```

in main component.html:

```
{{selectedQmgr}}
```

can you tell me what i am missing.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a shared service and inject this service in the components and whean you change any property of that service will reflect to other component because it's the same service.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private currentValue : number = 0;

  update() { 
    this.currentValue++;
  }

  get selectedValue(){
    return this.currentValue
  }

}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-example)

Comment: thanks for the info. I am importing a in b and trying to change a from b .. 
in b - i have sidebar with button click events, in a - i have maincontent. Idea is onclick to make a call to electron , electron to give json array back and to visualise it in maincontent. not sure if this shared service is correct  choice ? 
in angularjs i have $scope.data = json .. but here a little bit complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a few ways to tackle this. I don't use the method you are attempting much so I can't really comment on what might be going on, although I think you should be able to inject the parent component into the child. The other two methods I have used are:

1. Create a service that gets injected into both and have the shared
   data stored in there. Probably as a BehaviorSubject or some other
   alternative from Rxjs that can emit the values.
2. Create an @Output EventEmitter in the child component that you can emit the value
   through, then bind to it in the template of your parent component.

Edit: Adding an example of the EventEmitter option since Muhammed already posted an example of a shared service.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'menu-item-component',
  ... // omitted properties
})
export class MenuItemComponent {
  @Output() groupSelected: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {}

  showGroup(item: NavItem){
     //this.ComponentMain.selectedGroup = 'test'; - nothing is happening
     this.groupSelected.emit('test'); //Emit whatever value you want here.
  }
}
```

Now in your main component (and this is assuming that the menu items are direct children) somewhere in your html template file you'd have:

```
<menu-item-component (groupSelected)="callbackFunction($event)">Sample</menu-item-component>
```

callbackFunction() would be a function on your main component that would be passed the value emitted from the menu item.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-component',
  ... // omitted properties
})
export class MainComponent {
  selectedGroup: string = null;
  constructor() {}

  callbackFunction(group: string) {
    //Do something with the value here.
    this.selectedGroup = group;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer but it 's will be greate if you create an example this will be helpful and give more value to your answer  , in my answer I try to give just a basic exaple of shared service  ,thanks 